# Descending chain of subalgebras of $k[x,y]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, jacobian-conjecture

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Let $\{R_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a descending chain of $k$-subalgebras of $k[x,y]$: $k[x,y]=:R_0 \supseteq R_1 \supseteq R_2 \supseteq \ldots$,
such that the Krull dimension of each $R_i$ is $2$.

> Is it possible to somehow characterize such $R_i$'s with the additional property that $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}R_i=k$? (I am not sure what a good characterization should be).

**Example:** $R_0=k[x,y]$, $R_1=k[x^2,y^2]$, $R_2=k[x^4,y^4]$, etc., namely, $R_i=k[x^{2^i},y^{2^i}]$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$; in this case, $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}R_i=k$.
Notice that if we define $f:(x,y) \mapsto (x^2,y^2)$, then $R_i=f^i(R_0)$,
$i \in \mathbb{N}$.

A similar question of mine is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914547/descending-chain-of-algebras) (in the comments I explain the connection to the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture).

**A trivial remark:** If $g$ is an automorphism of $k[x,y]$, then, if we take $R_i=g^i(R_0)$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we get that $R_i=k[x,y]$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, so $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} R_i=k[x,y]$. In other words, if 
$\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} R_i \subsetneq k[x,y]$, then $g$ is not an automorphism of $k[x,y]$. In particular, if
$\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} R_i =k$, then $g$ is not an automorphism of $k[x,y]$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm unclear on what would constitute an answer to this question. There is a lot of latitude in choosing the $R_i$'s if you do not insist that $R_i = f^i(R_0)$ for some endomorphism $f$ of $R_0$. One just needs to make sure any polynomial is eventually outside of some $R_i$. For example, any sequence of $R_i$'s that are generated by elements of increasing degree would suffice.